# How do I import Firebase to my Apache Cordova project?

Tags: javascript, android, visual-studio, mobile, apache-cordova

I just installed "Mobile development with Javascript" from Visual Studio Workloads.I created an Apache Cordova project and now i want to open  my firebase database. How can I do it? I know I have to import some tools, but I don't know how to do it. Thank you!

Comment: I googled "cordova firebase" and found this: https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plugins available for that - [cordova-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase) being one

Comment: Yes, i understand and i saw this page. But I can't set this plugin to my project. I downloaded the google-services.json and add <plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="^2.0.0" /> in my config.xml and here is my code and is not working. What am I omitting?                                                   
            var bigOne = document.getElementById('bigOne');
            var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('table2/x/email');
            dbRef.on('value', snap => bigOne.innerText = snap.val());

Comment: Did you use `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase --save` on the command line in your root project to add the plugin?

Comment: @GabiAlex what? Didn't you build your Cordova project with the command line?